# insertAfter() Breaking Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle, insertafter

I have the following markup that consists of 3 chunks of content, each containing a heading and some content:

```
<div class="feed-panels-expanding">
    <div class="feed">

        <section>

            <h2><a href="#">Heading One</a></h2>
            <p>Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin.</p>

            <div class="content">
                <p>Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor.</p>
                <p>Lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed molestie augue sit amet leo consequat posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
                <p>Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis.</p>
            </div>

        </section>

        <section>

            <h2><a href="#">Heading Two</a></h2>
            <p>Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin.</p>

            <div class="content">
                <p>Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor.</p>
                <p>Lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed molestie augue sit amet leo consequat posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
                <p>Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis.</p>
            </div>

        </section>

        <section>

            <h2><a href="#">Heading Three</a></h2>
            <p>Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin.</p>

            <div class="content">
                <p>Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor.</p>
                <p>Lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed molestie augue sit amet leo consequat posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
                <p>Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis.</p>
            </div>

        </section>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want it so that clicking each heading does a expands / closes the content beneath.

I'm trying to get it so that the jQuery script takes care of hiding all but the first paragraph. In order to do this, it takes the first paragraph and moves it outside of `.content`. It then hides `.content`

```
// feed-panels-expanding
$('.feed-panels-expanding section').each(function() {

    $(this).find('h2 a').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle(250);
        return false;
    });

    $(this).find('.content p:first').insertAfter($(this).find('h2'));
    $(this).find('.content').hide();

});
```

However there's something the script really doesn't like about me moving the first `p` element in each content block. If I remove that line, the script works fine and all of the panels expand / contract when the relevant heading is clicked.

But with that line of code in there, the script does nothing. I can get an `alert` statement to pop up when I click the headings, but it just ignores the `.content` elements

Comment: Why move the first paragraph outside of `.content`? Why not just hide everything but the first paragraph from the start?

Comment: If I did that, I don't think the `slideToggle` would work properly?

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/97xfsn12/?

Comment: @pealo86 see my answer for an example - no need to move that paragraph around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next()` looks for the next element after the one you selected. And it is no longer the `content` element. The next element is the paragraph you just inserted.

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.content').slideToggle(250);
```

Comment: ah but I thought specifying `.content` in the parenthesis would solve this? does it have to be the very next element rather than the next element of a particular class?

Comment: It's the next element only, the class is just a filter making sure the next element matches a class. What you're looking for is `siblings` instgead

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/next/ *"Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector."*

Comment: perfect thank you! :D you were so quick to answer Stack Overflow tells me a need to wait 7 mins before I can mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2c331mb/2/).

All content divs are hidden initially besides the first content div. No need to remove it and place it elsewhere - CSS can find it by looking for the first `section` element and then finding the `.content` div within that.

As for the jQuery, the click event looks for the `section` parent element, then searches for the `.content` div within that to toggle the display.

Comment: `closest` is always a better alternative to `parent().parent()` as is it is more "robust" when the DOM changes.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie thanks, made that change in my answer

Comment: As you went to the trouble of *not* changing the DOM, I like your answer better. +1

Answer (score 0):

`next` *only* looks at the single following sibling element, then applies the filter.

Simple fix for now. Use `nextAll` with your `.content` filter:

```
$(this).find('h2 a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.content').slideToggle(250);
    return false;
});
```

`nextAll` only looks at subsequent elements, so is more efficient than `siblings` when you know the elements follow afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

i think that your problem is the selection of the content check the snippet

you did $(this).parent() witch is the h2 tag not the .content and use find better to find the element .content

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('.content').slideToggle(250);
```

```js
// feed-panels-expanding
$('.feed-panels-expanding section').each(function() {

    $(this).find('h2 a').click(function() {
      //you did $(this).parent() witch is the h2 tag not the scetion and use find better
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.content').slideToggle(250);
        return false;
    });

    $(this).find('.content p:first').insertAfter($(this).find('h2'));
    $(this).find('.content').hide();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feed-panels-expanding">
    <div class="feed">

        <section>

            <h2><a href="#">Heading One</a></h2>
            <p>Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin.</p>

            <div class="content">
                <p>Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor.</p>
                <p>Lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed molestie augue sit amet leo consequat posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
                <p>Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis.</p>
            </div>

        </section>

        <section>

            <h2><a href="#">Heading Two</a></h2>
            <p>Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin.</p>

            <div class="content">
                <p>Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor.</p>
                <p>Lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed molestie augue sit amet leo consequat posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
                <p>Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis.</p>
            </div>

        </section>

        <section>

            <h2><a href="#">Heading Three</a></h2>
            <p>Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin.</p>

            <div class="content">
                <p>Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor.</p>
                <p>Lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed molestie augue sit amet leo consequat posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
                <p>Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis.</p>
            </div>

        </section>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Putting your entire answer in the snippet, without explanation, is not a great idea (even though your code will work) :(

Comment: i did explain in the snippet check it

Comment: And if nobody bothers to open it? :) Just trying to be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is an accordion.

More here: http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-an-accordion-with-html-css-jquery